# how to download node modules to Angular 2 project

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-template, npm-install, git-bash

I have  git project downloaded in dir d:/myapp. I have npm 3.10.10 and node 6.11 install on my windows machine. But while runnning Install npm from git bash commd line to install all dependent node module...i get error as below:

$ install npm
install: missing destination file operand after 'npm'
Try 'install --help' for more information.

Comment: try `npm install --save`

Answer (score 11):

The command to install npm modules is just `npm install`. It looks you are doing `install npm install`, with an extra "install" before npm.

Here are the official docs for [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) showing the different options. Note that `npm` is always the first command for any `npm` commands, whether it's `install`, `start`, etc.